# CMake subdirectory litters main directory with its project files

Tags: cmake

I am trying to use a library in a project. I downloaded it and put it in the folder where I keep all the external libraries needed by the project.

When I add the library as a subdirectory in the CMakeLists.txt and run cmake, the CMakeLists.txt of the library copies its license (replacing my license) and lots of other files to the CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.

I do not want them there. I want to somehow keep those files in the own directory of the library. How do I achieve this?

Can I somehow set CMAKE_BINARY_DIR before calling the subdirectory?

I would prefer not to edit the CMakeLists.txt of the library.

Here are the reproducing files:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(MYPROJECT)

add_subdirectory(annoyer)
```

annoyer/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(ANNOYER)

file(COPY annoyingfile.txt DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

When `cmake CMakeLists.txt` is run, `annoyingfile.txt` is moved to the top directory. I want it to stay at `annoyer/`.

Comment: Have you tried `set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR annoyer)` before `add_subdirectory(annoyer)`?

Comment: Oddly enough, it works. AFAIK it should not be possible to set CMAKE_BINARY_DIR and after a bit of googling it seems that it cannot be set on some platforms.

Comment: I give up with this library. Now it says `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (message): Not allowed to run in-source build!`

Answer (score 1):

`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` always refers to the binary directory of the *top-level* project.

Use `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to refer to refer to the binary directory of the *current* project.

The same is true for `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`/`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`.

Comment: I did nearly that in the end. I thought I could find a library to replace this one, but actually ended up not finding any as good. I forked the project and fixed the CMakeLists like your answer suggests. +1 but no accept because this does not meet the no-modification requirement.

Comment: There was no "no modification" requirement in the question. However, if this is a totally external library which probably does not change, I suggest to keep it as a separate library and simply use `target_link_libraries` and `include_directories` (probably together with either a) `FIND_PACKAGE` (if available) b) `FIND_LIBRARY` or c) a hard-coded path (using `SET(...)` for readability)

Comment: Sorry, it probably was not clear enough. "I would prefer not to edit the CMakeLists.txt of the library." was a part of the question. Will any of those suggestions compile the library too?

Comment: Sorry, missed that comment. No, you would compile it beforehand as it is an external dependency. Why would you need to include it in your project (source-wise) if it is never manipulated?

Comment: Good question. I suppose I thought it would be more portable if the library was always compiled for the platform. Now I see that it is better to let the user compile it separately if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the optional second argument to `add_subdirectory()` which lets you specify the binary directory.  Like this:

```
add_subdirectory(annoyer, annoyer_bin)
```

That should avoid the issue of annoyer annoying you with annoyances about in-source builds, and also segregate its output in a separate subdirectory.

Comment: This creates a folder called annoyer_bin and puts CMake stuff in it. Annoyingfile.txt is still being copied to the top directory.

Comment: Then probably you need to patch the annoyer's CMakeLists to write the file in a nicer way.

Comment: And this is the problem. The real library has dozens of CMakeLists.txt's in their own subdirectories, all doing this same stuff. I'd prefer not touching them. Luckily the library has lots of well behaving alternatives. Lesson of today: Never use OpenImageIO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ExternalProject module. That will confine it to its own top-level directory.

You'll then need to set up dependencies explicitly and use the generated binary files by one of the many methods.